Bottom bar color issue
I am developing a simple app with Flutter like a university project. In my app I develop this file .dart to include a bottom bar in all the pages to navigate between them:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onHomePressed;
  final VoidCallback onCareerPressed;
  final VoidCallback onProgressPressed;
  final VoidCallback onAccountPressed;
  final int selectedIndex;

  const BottomBar({
    super.key,
    required this.onHomePressed,
    required this.onCareerPressed,
    required this.onProgressPressed,
    required this.onAccountPressed,
    this.selectedIndex = 0,
  });

  @override
  _BottomBarState createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  late int _selectedIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedIndex = widget.selectedIndex;
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        widget.onHomePressed();
        break;
      case 1:
        widget.onCareerPressed();
        break;
      case 2:
        widget.onProgressPressed();
        break;
      case 3:
        widget.onAccountPressed();
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).bottomNavigationBarTheme.backgroundColor,
      selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).bottomNavigationBarTheme.selectedItemColor,
      unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).bottomNavigationBarTheme.unselectedItemColor,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.timer_sharp),
          label: 'Allenamento',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
          label: 'Carriera',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.insights),
          label: 'Progressi',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
          label: 'Account',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


These are the colors that I want to use:
class AppColors {
  static const Color backgroundColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 29, 0);
  static const Color backgroundSezioni = Color.fromARGB(132, 255, 255, 255);
  static const Color backgroundCalendario = Color.fromARGB(145, 255, 255, 255);


  static const Color bottomBarColor = Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 21, 2);
  static const Color barIcon = Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
  static const Color barIconSelect = Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 255, 16);

}

The problem is that when I include it in all my pages the background color seems not work or better probably there's something that override my color that give white color to the background.
An example of my four pages is this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:level_up/repository/category_repo.dart';
import 'package:level_up/pages/allenamenti.dart';
import 'package:level_up/pages/account.dart';
import 'package:level_up/pages/carriera.dart';
import 'package:level_up/pages/progressi.dart';
import 'package:level_up/style/stile.dart';
import 'package:level_up/utils/bottom_bar.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key, this.title = 'LevelUp'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onBottomBarSelected(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
        );
        break;
      case 1:
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Carriera()),
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Progressi()),
        );
        break;
      case 3:
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Account()),
        );
        break;
    }
  }

  void _navigateToAllenamenti(String categoria) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AllenamentiPage(categoria: categoria),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: fetchCategory(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Errore: ${snapshot.error}'));
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Nessun dato disponibile'));
          } else {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: DimApp.margineLato,
                  child: Text(
                    'Seleziona il tipo di allenamento:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var category = snapshot.data![index];
                      String imagePath = category['img_url'];
                      String categoria = category['_id'];

                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _navigateToAllenamenti(categoria);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          margin: DimApp.margineMedio,
                          height: 200.0,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: DimApp.raggioSezioni,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  imagePath,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  height: 200.0,
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                    return const Center(
                                        child: Icon(Icons.error));
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    categoria,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 19.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onHomePressed: () => _onBottomBarSelected(0),
        onCareerPressed: () => _onBottomBarSelected(1),
        onProgressPressed: () => _onBottomBarSelected(2),
        onAccountPressed: () => _onBottomBarSelected(3),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This page recover data from an API and generate the different categories, but I think that the content of my page don't affect the behaviour of the bottom bar because it doesn't work in any pages.
For completeness these are the main.dart file and the app.dart file that launch the application:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:level_up/app.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  WindowOptions windowOptions = const WindowOptions(
    //Pixel 8 pro
    size: Size(448, 998),
  );

  if (!kIsWeb &&
      !Platform.isAndroid &&
      !Platform.isIOS &&
      (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS)) {
    await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
    windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
      await windowManager.show();
      await windowManager.focus();
    });
  }

  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}






import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:level_up/pages/login.dart';
import 'package:level_up/style/stile.dart';

class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'LevelUp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
        ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
        bottomNavigationBarTheme: const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.bottomBarColor,
          selectedItemColor: AppColors.barIconSelect,
          unselectedItemColor: AppColors.barIcon,
        ),
      ),
      home: const Login(),
    );
  }
}


I tried to import the bottom bar in another project and it seems work, but in this project no

Alessandro, the color issue might be related to the accentColor and elevation. Your bottom navigation bar code could be simplified. Let me know if you'd like to see an example.

@raghav042 oh yes, please let me know if can help me to solve this problem or improve my code. If you want I can link you my git repo for this project, so you can see the entire project and maybe help me faster
